# ROI augmentation in keras: scipy.ndimage transformations

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, keras, ndimage

I've got an image with regions of interest.
I would like to apply random transformations to this image, while keeping the regions of interest correct.

My code is taking a list of boxes in this format `[x_min, y_min, x_max, y_max]`.
It then converts the boxes into a list of vertices `[up_left, up_right, down_right, down_left]` for every box. This is a list of vectors. So I can apply the transformation to the vectors.

The next step is looking for the new `[x_min, y_min, x_max, y_max]` in the list of transformed vertices.

My first application was rotations, they work fine:

[image: input] [image: output]

Here is the corresponding code. The first part is taken from the [keras](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/keras/preprocessing/image.py) codebase, scroll down to the NEW CODE comment.
If I get the code to work, I would be interested in integrating it into keras. So I'm trying to integrate my code into their image preprocessing infrastructure:

```
def random_rotation_with_boxes(x, boxes, rg, row_axis=1, col_axis=2, channel_axis=0,
                    fill_mode='nearest', cval=0.):
    """Performs a random rotation of a Numpy image tensor. 
       Also rotates the corresponding bounding boxes

    # Arguments
        x: Input tensor. Must be 3D.
        boxes: a list of bounding boxes [xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax], values in [0,1].
        rg: Rotation range, in degrees.
        row_axis: Index of axis for rows in the input tensor.
        col_axis: Index of axis for columns in the input tensor.
        channel_axis: Index of axis for channels in the input tensor.
        fill_mode: Points outside the boundaries of the input
            are filled according to the given mode
            (one of `{'constant', 'nearest', 'reflect', 'wrap'}`).
        cval: Value used for points outside the boundaries
            of the input if `mode='constant'`.

    # Returns
        Rotated Numpy image tensor.
        And rotated bounding boxes
    """

    # sample parameter for augmentation
    theta = np.pi / 180 * np.random.uniform(-rg, rg)

    # apply to image
    rotation_matrix = np.array([[np.cos(theta), -np.sin(theta), 0],
                                [np.sin(theta), np.cos(theta), 0],
                                [0, 0, 1]])

    h, w = x.shape[row_axis], x.shape[col_axis]
    transform_matrix = transform_matrix_offset_center(rotation_matrix, h, w)
    x = apply_transform(x, transform_matrix, channel_axis, fill_mode, cval)
    
    
    # -------------------------------------------------
    # NEW CODE FROM HERE
    # -------------------------------------------------
    # apply to vertices
    vertices = boxes_to_vertices(boxes)
    vertices = vertices.reshape((-1, 2))

    # apply offset to have pivot point at [0.5, 0.5]
    vertices -= [0.5, 0.5]

    # apply rotation, we only need the rotation part of the matrix
    vertices = np.dot(vertices, rotation_matrix[:2, :2])
    vertices += [0.5, 0.5]

    boxes = vertices_to_boxes(vertices)

    return x, boxes, vertices
```

As you can see, they are using `scipy.ndimage` to apply the transformation to an image.

My bounding boxes have coordinates in `[0,1]`, the center is `[0.5, 0.5]`. The rotation needs to be applied around `[0.5, 0.5]` as pivot point. It would be possible to use homogenous coordinates and matrices to shift, rotate and shift the vectors. That's what they do for the image.
There is an existing `transform_matrix_offset_center` function, but that offsets to `float(width)/2 + 0.5`. The `+0.5` makes this unsuitable for my coordinates in `[0, 1]`. So I'm shifting the vectors myself.

For rotations, this code works fine.
I thought it would be generally applicable.

But for zooming, this fails in a strange way. The code is pretty much identical:

```
vertices -= [0.5, 0.5]

# apply zoom, we only need the zoom part of the matrix
vertices = np.dot(vertices, zoom_matrix[:2, :2])
vertices += [0.5, 0.5]
```

The output is this:

[image: zoom 1][image: zoom 2]

There seems to be a variety of problems:

- The shifting is broken. In image 1, the ROI and the corresponding image part almost don't overlap
- The coordinates seem to be switched. In image 2, the ROI and the image seem to be scaled differently along x and y axes.

I tried switching the axes by using `(zoom_matrix[:2, :2].T)[::-1, ::-1]`.
That leads to this:[image: zoom3]

Now the scale factor is broken? I've tried many different variations on this matrix multiplication, transposing, mirroring, changing the scale factors, etc. I can't seem to get it right.

And in any case, I think that the original code should be correct. It works for rotations, after all.
At this point, I'm thinking whether this is a peculiarity of scipy's ndimage resampling ?

Is this a mistake in my math, or is something missing to truly emulate the scipy ndimage resampling ?

I've put the full source code on pastebin.
Only small parts are updated by me, actually this is code from [keras](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/keras/preprocessing/image.py):
https://pastebin.com/tsHnLLgy

The code to use the new augmentations and create these images is here:
https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/gist/lhk/b8f30e9f30c5d395b99188a53524c53e

**UPDATE:**

If the zoom factors are inverted, the transformation works.
For zoom, this operation is simple and can be expressed as:

```
# vertices is an array of shape [number of vertices, 2]
vertices *= [1/zx, 1/zy]
```

This corresponds to applying the inverse transform to the vertices.
In the context of image resampling, this could make sense. An image could be resampled like this

- create a coordinate vector for every pixel.
- apply the inverse transform to every vector
- interpolate the original image to find the value the vector is now pointing at
- write this value to the output image at the original position

But for rotation, I didn't invert the matrix and the operation worked correctly.

The question itself, how to fix this, seems answered. But I don't understand why.